# c# - running a function with another thread using UI thread items

Tags: c#, multithreading, function, visual-studio-2015

I have a public static method within a certain class. and it uses items ( combo box, datagridviews etc' ) created in the UI thread. I want to run this function from a new thread, but I get this message : 
"Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'CompanycheckedListBox' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

how can I run the function from a new thread and still use these items created in the UI thread?

I used this line of code : new Thread(delegate () { functionName();}).Start();

Comment: `Form.BeginInvoke` might help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You shouldn't run function which "manipulates" UI controls on other then UI thread. Instead - execute required calculation on other thread - return calculated data and update UI controls in correct environment

Comment: It is just as ``Fabio`` said, maybe explain why you are doing this. If you just want to execute your code at a later time ``NibblyPig's`` comment is for you, but if your "idea" is something else there might be different alternatives.

Comment: the function does manipulate some UI controls such as populating datagridviews and updating combo box (from within the function)

Comment: You should provide us with more information. What UI framework you are using `Winforms` or `WPF`. (If you talk about `DataGridView` then definitely `Winforms`). From where you get data which you uses for populating controls. Different approaches will be used if you load data from external resources(file system, database etc) or executing "long running" calculation on already existed in memory data.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: you can't. Those components can only be accessed on the ui thread. But there are ways to dispatch you function call onto the ui thread.

Most ui frameworks are completely single threaded. It is not allowed to access any component from a different thread than the ui thread.

You need to dispatch to current ui thread. Looking it at your control names, it looks either like a winforms or a WPF application.

In WinForms you need the following code to dispatch back to the ui thread:

```
public void UpdateUI(object parameter)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => UpdateUI(parameter)));
        return;
    }

    // Update or access here 
}
```

In WPF  the following snipped allows you to change the ui form a different thread:

```
public void UpdateUI(object parameter)
{
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => UpdateUI(parameter)));
       return;
    }

    // Do update or access here
}
```

The important thing to notice here, is that those functions will be executed on the UI thread and not on the calling thread.

Edit: the object parameter is completely optional. It was intended as a example on how to use this method with a function with parameters.

Comment: thanks a lot. but if the function runs on the UI thread, it won't leave the UI thread free. So what does this method provides me with ?

Comment: and about the 'object parameter'  - what do I put in there? the function that I would like to invoke?

Comment: In WPF if you use `data-binding` then updating data source(viewmodel) on other thread will automatically update UI control  without manually dispatching it.

Comment: Yes the function will begin on ui thread. But using this method only the ui access is dispatched, all time consuming actions can be executed on a background thread.